# What happens when two Interference powers oppose each other?

Tags: wild-talents, one-roll-engine

In Wild Talents, a power with the Interference extra serves to reduce an opposing power's width:

> Interference allows your power to reduce the width of an opposed roll *before* the resolution of all rolls. [...] On a success, in the resolution phase your Interference roll reduces the width of the opposed roll by its width *before any other roll is parsed*.

<sup>(Essential Edition p. 127 - emphases in original)</sup>

What happens if the opposed roll *itself* has Interference? Does the strength of the Interference effect get "set" before the powers reduce each others' width? Do opposed Interferences cancel each other out? If the powers have the same width, do both fail, or neither? (I'm assuming both powers are in hard dice, for consistent widths.)

I'm hoping for a RAW answer, but if this hasn't been addressed anywhere then something looser is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no answer RAW that I have found.
Second, there is a possible cinematic solution.

We will start with page 118 in Essentials:

> Interference is an Extra that lets the power’s dice directly disrupt
>   some other character’s action. On a successful roll each of your dice
>   becomes a gobble die that removes a die of that height or lower from
>   your target’s matching sets, before the target’s action takes effect.
>   If you have a 4d power with Interference and you roll 2x7 with it, you
>   can remove up to two dice of height 7 or less from your opponent’s set
>   or sets. Interference costs +3 per die.

Then page 127

> Your Interference roll’s height must match or exceed the height of the
>   roll that you’re opposing. Unlike an ordinary opposed roll, however,
>   it does not need to match or beat the width of the roll you’re
>   opposing

and

> The kinds of actions your power can oppose with Interference is always
>   up to the GM. Interference on a Defends Power Quality usually opposes
>   attack rolls; Interference on a Useful Power Quality usually opposes
>   noncombat rolls, depending on the nature and description of your power
>   and the action you’re trying to oppose. Interference on Attacks can
>   oppose just about any kind of action, but the GM is encouraged to play
>   up unintended consequences when you, say, distract someone with blasts
>   of supernova fire.

And Page 58 in regards to Resolution of Rolls

> The character with the widest roll always acts first. If two sets are
>   equally wide, the taller roll goes first. All actions are resolved in
>   order of width.

So, we will assume in your case, that you have two people fighting, with two different powers.
Let's say we have a Blaster with a Harm (A;R) power, with Interference, at 4HD.
We also have a Teleporter with a Teleport (D;S) power, with Interference, at 4HD.

Inteference says it disrupts the action, equal or less in height, with no care about width. So, both of them go off, and both of them go off before the action. But we still need to resolve a Tie. They both have the same width. They both have the same height.

There is no RAW to what happens, that I have found. At this point, it is unfortunately up to the GM.

My ruling has been that in those cases, it's where we get those power vs power shots in cinema (The magic meeting in the middle, so to speak), or where two people punch each other at the exact same time, and maybe their fists meet, or they get thrown back, but are otherwise good to go.

In this case, the case of Interference, I would apply them to the other at the exact same time. Each one gobbles 4 dice. Three are needed to cancel the powers (This of course leaves each with 1 in case of multiple actions, or attacks from other places).

> So, Blaster fires his ray, which excites the atoms around the area
>   enough that it temporarily disrupts the teleportation. But the
>   teleportation phasing left the Teleporter unharmed.

If you feel like you need to have a winner, however, you can have each roll a single die, and apply that height as the winner. That way it can change from action to action. This can show the example of cinema where the two powers meet, instead of cancelling the other out, one does eventually win.... but I prefer that that come about with an augment, or a change, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read it, the order of resolution on p. 58 of Essential Edition would apply -- generally, whichever Interference Power has the widest match will reduce the width of the tallest set in the other.  Much of the time, of course, this means that the faster application of the Power will cancel the slower by eliminating a single 2x set.  At the least, the wider roll will be unaffected, having already been resolved.

Given your edge-case assumption of Powers with matching Hard Dice widths, and the further assumption that neither player rolls additional 10s (which would widen the set), my reading is that the widest secondary set, tallest secondary set, or highest loose die (in that order), would break the tie, with the winner being resolved first (and again, cancelling the loser's Interfering Hard Dice set).  With a large dice pool, there's surely the possibility of highest loose die still being a tie; I don't see a RAW resolution for that case (in the spirit of One Roll, I'd use the highest unmatched loose die at this point).

See also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24823/what-happens-when-two-combatants-attack-rolls-have-the-same-height-and-width?rq=1) for resolution of tied rolls.

Comment: I wouldn't expect an interference power with hard dice to also have any other kinds of dice. There wouldn't be any secondary sets or loose dice to break the tie with. If a 4hd power with interference opposes a 4hd power with interference, there must be _some_ way of resolving it.